# How to add uncommented line after commented line in insert mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

When in insert mode in Vim, if we're editing a commented line and hit enter, the next line will start out commented.

Is there any keyboard shortcut or possible programmable shortcut, say a shift+enter or the like, with which we can have the next line be uncommented?

As a note since this question has been marked as a duplicate, I do not want to disable this feature. I want to keep it enabled, but use the shortcut to overrule it whenever necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: @phd please note my update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> As a note since this question has been marked as a duplicate, I do not want to disable this feature. I want to keep it enabled, but use the shortcut to overrule it whenever necessary.

after pressed `Enter` (INSERT mode), press `ctrl-u`

Comment: That is passable but not what I really would prefer, which is one "gesture" rather than two. Thanks for the help though, @kent!

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using `imap` to assign that <ctrl-u> to something else, though.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mapping for `enter` followed by `ctrl+u` in insert mode.

For example, to use `shift+enter`:

```
inoremap <S-CR> <CR><C-u>
```

Comment: Thank you @diogo-campos.

Didn't really work for me as of now, but it makes sense. I'll debug it and let you know if I can get it to work.